# Find all submatches to reorder a sentence

Tags: vim

Using gvim 8.0 on windows 7, I'd like to reorder parts of a sentence pattern:

before:

```
Execution time: 0.22s Statement 1 of 8 finished (2018-05-18 06:48:35.231)
Execution time: 0.22s Statement 1 of 8 finished (2018-05-18 06:54:01.259)
Execution time: 0.22s Statement 1 of 8 finished (2018-05-18 07:05:54.480)
<et al>
```

after:

```
Statement 1 of 8 finished (2018-05-18 06:48:35.231) Execution time: 0.22s 
Statement 1 of 8 finished (2018-05-18 06:54:01.259) Execution time: 0.22s
Statement 1 of 8 finished (2018-05-18 07:05:54.480) Execution time: 0.22s 
<et al>
```

I thought I would capture submatches, and then substitute; I can't seem to get more than one submatch - I tried:

```
/\v^([^S]*)
```

and that matched the first submatch I want, but then:

```
/\v^([^S]*),([^S]*)
```

doesn't seem to find anything.

Is this the right approach? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your input sentences you could use the substitution:

```
 %s/\v(.*) (Statement.*)/\2 \1/g
```

This will capture the text before `Statement` and put it at the end of the sentence. Output:

```
Statement 1 of 8 finished (2018-05-18 06:48:35.231) Execution time: 0.22s
Statement 1 of 8 finished (2018-05-18 06:54:01.259) Execution time: 0.22s
Statement 1 of 8 finished (2018-05-18 07:05:54.480) Execution time: 0.22s
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no comma in your text so why do you have one in your search pattern?

I find `awk` more intuitive:

```
:%!awk '{print $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $1, $2, $3}'
```

Comment: The commas are there because I borrowed the pattern from a CSV example in Practical Vim. 'S' should be the deliimiter in this case. /\v^([^S]*)S([^S]*) gets me pretty close. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
:g/^E/exec "norm! dtSA \<esc>p"

g ........... globally
^E .......... at the lines that start with "E"
exec ........ execute
normal! ..... in normal mode
dtS ......... delete [un]till before next "S"
A ........... start insert mode at the end of the line
............. add one space
p ........... paste
```